# Appending CSS using appendChild to document doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to manually add CSS for font-face to a new window using this code:

```
const css = '@font-face {font-family:Roboto; src:url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");}';
const head = this.externalWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const style = this.externalWindow.document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.appendChild(this.externalWindow.document.createTextNode(css));
head.appendChild(style);
```

When I do this it does not seem to recognise the CSS as CSS and even in the source code it isn't highlighted as CSS.

[image: broken css image]

But when I do this and write the style using `document.write` it work fine and loads the font as a font.

```
this.externalWindow.document.write('<html><head><style>' + '@font-face {font-family:Roboto ;src:url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");}' + '.inner{font-family: Roboto;font-size: 40pt;text-align: justify;}' + '</style></head><body onload="window.print();window.close()"><p class="head">' + this.headContents + '</p> <p class="inner">' + this.innerContents + '</p> <p class="sign">' + this.signContents + '</p></body></html>');
```

[image: working css image]

Comment: Google offers using `.innerHTML` as an alternative to using `.createTextNode()`. There's also [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) which allows you to manipulate stylesheets directly in the DOM.

Comment: How would I use that?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Add an empty `<style>` element to the `externalWindow.document`
2. Then grab the `stylesheet` object from that `<style>` element
3. Then populate the `stylesheet` object with style rules, using `insertRule`

**Example:**

```
// Append <style> element to <head> of externalWindow.document
const head = this.externalWindow.document.head;
const style = this.externalWindow.document.createElement('style');
head.appendChild(style);


// Grab external stylesheet object
const externalStylesheet = style.sheet;


// Insert style rules into external stylesheet
externalStylesheet.insertRule('@font-face {font-family: Roboto; src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");}', 0);
externalStylesheet.insertRule('.inner {font-family: Roboto; font-size: 40pt; text-align: justify;}', 1);
```

Comment: Sadly this isn't working as expected. The `<style>` is empty. I also had to modify the above to be `const externalStylesheet = style.sheet as CSSStyleSheet;`

Comment: On JSFiddle I could only get it to work with `font` and a class.  Attempting to apply `font-family` to the entire document wouldn't work for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/x08mLec9/3/

Answer (score 0):

`.createTextNode` assumes that your input is text, not code, and escapes it as such ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)).

Instead, try using `style.innerHTML = css`.

Comment: "*`.createTextNode` assumes that your input is text, not code, and escapes it as such*": Where is this information from? The linked site doesn't mention that. And, if you inspect a website, with pre-generated `<style>`s, you'll see that their `.childNodes` are `Text` objects...